# onepage checkout js error

Tags: onepage-checkout

currently i am working with a magento shopping site.I am newbie to magento. When i tried to login via one page both login and create button are disabled. Default login and create account working fine.

It shows the error uncaught TypeError: $j(...).foundation is not a function

please help me to solve the problem.Thanks in advance.

please check this link http://qwertykart.com/checkout/onepage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in reference to chat with you.

you are using https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-delivery-check-by-zip-code.html
this module for checking shipping availability. in this module their is one bug that to get a status when they are making request they are trying to call such a action which is not exist.

in **availability_checkout_js.phtml**  they are calling `zipcodeavailability/index/checkoutpage` which is not exist it should be like `zipcodeavailability/index/cartpageavailable`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: should i make any change in onepage/login.phtml

Comment: can you please come for chat at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40253/chat-with-siby-xavier

Comment: replace $j with jQuery

Comment: bro are u there?

Comment: yes i am here how can i help u.

Comment: please come to the above room